# Bash finding old version of executable in /usr/bin after installing into /usr/local/bin, why?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I installed a new executable into `/usr/local/bin` and this directory is in my path ahead of `/usr/bin` . But, bash still prefers the version in `/usr/bin` until I start a new bash process. The `which` command clearly sees that the preferred version is in `/usr/local/bin`.

Bash must be caching executable file locations. Is it possible to refresh it to now see the new version in /usr/local/bin without having to restart bash?

Answer (score 3):

[This Unix & Linux answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/5610/108618) is relevant:

> `bash` does cache the full path to a command.  You can verify that the
>   command you are trying to execute is hashed with the `type` command:
>
> ```
> $ type svnsync
> svnsync is hashed (/usr/local/bin/svnsync)
> ```
>
> To clear the entire cache:
>
> ```
> $ hash -r
> ```
>
> Or just one entry:
>
> ```
> $ hash -d svnsync
> ```
>
> For additional information, consult `help hash` and `man bash`.